# Col width of table doesn't work when I add a nested Table in HTML

Tags: c#, html, excel, model-view-controller, html-table

I have an html Table that I'm exporting to Excel. Everything worked fine until I added a nested Table then the `<col>` property stopped having its effect. Any ideas how to resolve it?

```
<table width="570px" style="table-layout:fixed; width:430pt">
<colgroup>
<col width="190px" style="width:143pt; "/>
<col width="190px" style="width:143pt"/>
<col width="190px" style="width:143pt"/>
<col width="190px" style="width:143pt"/>

</colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>Test1</td>
<td>Test1</td>
<td>Test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test2</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <table width = "100%" style=" width:100%" >
        <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide the code.If there is any error please mention that too in the question.Also you have not mentioned the programming language

Comment: I added the html table , im using it in MVC C# . The error is that the col aren't displayed as set in the colgroup